# How to run my .jl file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, vscode-debugger

I installed VSCode and the Julia extension. Supposedly by hitting Ctrol+F5 I should be able to run the code in the file in the editor. That does not happen. Instead, I get the following message:

```
command 'language-julia.debug.getActiveJuliaEnvironment' not found
```

The dialog box also contains a button that says "Open 'Launch.json'". When I click on that button I see the following code:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "julia",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Run active Julia file",
            "program": "${file}",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "juliaEnv": "${command:activeJuliaEnvironment}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I Googled for help on this and tried several things but could not get VSCode to run my file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you instal Julia itself (from julialang.org) ? The VSCode Julia extension is only a plugin for VSCode, it hasn't Julia embedded...

Comment: @Antonello - Thanks for your comment. Yes, I installed Julia from julialang.org. I solved the problem by uninstalling VSCode with the help of an uninstaller program (Revo Uninstaller Pro) and reinstalling it plus the Julia plugin. Everything worked fine after that.